# Do not repeat myself

Tags: typescript

I've got a typescript class:

```
class C {
  #fsm
  (...)
  startFoo(name: string) {
    this.#fsm.send('FOO', name)
    return this
  }
  startBar(name: string) {
    this.#fsm.send('BAR', name)
    return this
  }
  (...)
}
```

startFoo and startBar are just two examples but I have tens of similar functions and I was wondering how I could avoid to repeat myself.
Would it be possible with decorators?

Comment: What I don't understand is why not just make one `start` method and pass in the channel you want to send the name to?

Comment: just pass a second parameter that has the channel?  `start(name: string, channel: string)`

Comment: You mean like `startFoo: (name: string) => start(name)` ?

Comment: No like `start("someName", "FOO")`

Comment: The class consumer must not know "channels", the functions API must remain simple

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzeGRm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply, or I won't get notified)

Comment: @jcalz That's quite an elegant answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach.  First, we can add [a `protected` method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes) to which we can delegate all the calls to the `startFoo()`, `startBar()`, et cetera.  Let's call this method `startify()`, and it takes an extra argument called `type`:

```
class C {
    #fsm = {
        send(type: string, name: string) {
            console.log("I was sent type \"" + type + "\" and name \"" + name + "\"");
        }
    }
    protected startify(type: string, name: string) {
        this.#fsm.send(type, name);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now we want to add the `startXxx` methods to the class prototype, as well as letting the compiler know that class instances have these methods.  Let's walk through it:

```
const methodNames = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const;
```

The `methodNames` array contains all the (lowercase) names of the part after `start`, and I am assuming that these names, when converted `toUpperCase()`, is the value you want to pass to `startify()`.  I use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so that the compiler keeps track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the strings inside it.  You can make this as array long as you need (I added `"baz"` to demonstrate).

```
type MethodNames = typeof methodNames[number];
```

The `MethodNames` type is a helper and resolves to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the string literal types in `methodNames`.  In this case it is `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"`.

```
type CMethods = { [K in MethodNames as `start${Capitalize<K>}`]: { (name: string): C } };
```

The `CMethods` is an object type whose keys are `MethodNames` [remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) by [init-capping the first letter with the `Capitalize<T>` intrinsic utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) and prepending `"start"` to it.  So the keys here are `"startFoo"`, `"startBar"`, and `"startBaz"`.  The property values at these keys are methods that accept a `string` argument and produce a value of type `C`.  (The "right" return type would be [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), but this can't be represented externally to the class, so I'm not going to worry about it.  If you ever subclass `C`, the inherited methods will only be known to return `C` and not whatever the subclass is.  ‍♂️).  So `CMethods` is the part of the `C` instance type we'd like to add.  And here's how we add it:

```
interface C extends CMethods { }
```

This is known as [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).  With this line, the compiler now knows that every instance of `C` has all the methods from `CMethods` as well as anything declared inside `class C {}`.

Now the compiler knows about the methods, but we need to actually add them.  First let's make a helper function `capitalize()` that does at a value-level what `Capitalize<>` does at the type level:

```
const capitalize = <K extends string>(k: K) => k[0].toUpperCase() + k.slice(1) as Capitalize<K>;
```

And here we go... for each element of `methodNames`, we add to a method with the appropriate name to `C.prototype`, and this method is delegated to `startify` via [the `call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
methodNames.forEach(k => C.prototype[`start${capitalize(k)}`] = function (this: C, name: string) {
    return C.prototype.startify.call(this, k.toUpperCase(), name);
});
```

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const c = new C();
c.startBar("barf").startFoo("food")
// I was sent type "BAR" and name "barf"
// I was sent type "FOO" and name "food"
```

Looks good! The compiler expects `c.startBar()` to exist, and return a `C` so the calls can be chained.  And at runtime the call is actually delegated properly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.7.4#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-L4IEAIIAEquIEBT1I8RTYEY6GYdhVh4RC3hGHBADy7HkUEVFnBcNB0SAQA)